# Inserting Data in binary file in sorted format

Tags: c++, file-io, binary

I am trying to enter data through classes in a binary file using file handling. But what I am unable to do is to write data in a sorted manner. Like I can't figure out how can I uniquely identify one of the records I had inserted in the past in that particular file. Why I am trying to do so? Because I want to be able to perform operations like deleting, modifying a particular record. I tried using static variable but I want to hold that value until I run the program the next time which is not possible with static. BTW this is the class.

```
class question
{
    private:
    char question[500];
    char option1[25],option2[25],option3[25],option4[25];
    int answernumber;
    public:
    int qno;
    void createquestion(); // Just to to accept data into
                           // question,options,answernumebr.
}
```

Now the only problem is assigning qno which is question number. I am planning to use it as my Primary key( wrong to use this word) . But I just can't figure it out how to automatically assign it its corresponding values without user intervention? Any suggestions? 
EDIT:- I also tried to do this---> I thought of reading the last record entered and then extract the corresponding question number. And then assign that number and add 1 to it...so old_qno+1=new_qno..... But unfortunately didn't worked out too well. as All my questions were being assigned as question 1 only

Comment: @Harsh: Off topic I know, but what was the answer to the problem you were having before?

Comment: @Harsh: If I understand you right you can use the size of the file to assign qno. Suppose you have written 6 questions to your file numbered 1 to 6. Then the size of your file will be 6*sizeof(question). So the next question number will be (size of file)/sizeof(question) + 1. So all you need to know is how to get the size of a file. If I'm on the right lines I'll write that up as an answer.

Comment: @jahhaj About that..I still got that error...I tried to re- analyse my code and thought rewriting the function in a more efficient way . And before I could do that this problem arose..

Comment: @jahhaj  I think what you said should work.. Can you please tell how to know the file size?

Comment: @jahhaj I think you are basically trying to say that I should count the number of records?

Comment: Show some _code_, not editorialization.

Comment: @Harsh-What is the `qno` in respect to it's purpose? Is it a number that tracks all the users one by one such that the first user is 1 and the sixth is 6? You said you couldn't figure out how to do it w/o user intervention, but what does the user know of the `qno`?

Comment: @ildjarn But that code is full of errors and I know a big mistake that I am doing there..I declared a friend function so that I can use qno even if its private member...but then I was wrong in doing so for some obvious reason which can be easily seen from that code....And I don't want this question to be headed in a wrong direction..Moreover I abandoned that code...Should I post it?

Comment: @RobertoWilko qno is the question number. I am writing Questions onto a binary file..and I plan on fetching these questions in the project I am making which us on QUIZ. So I want to assign Question number to records/questions being inserted.......my interface would be consisting of 2 things (required in present conext) One is Settings and other is Play game....Now in this setting the admin can insert,modify,delete questions. Now How would this admin tell my program what question it has to delete?

Comment: Someone downvoted my questions. Thats sad :{

Comment: I think you're trying too hard. It sounds like you could just `qno++` each time you `createquestion` write that to the file like any other piece of the record. Next, the admin would obviously have to have some knowledge of this numbering system. So, they would likely be looking at the question number, and you simply say `Enter the question number you'd like to edit: `.

Comment: @Harsh: That was a strange error you had. I don't think there was too much wrong with your code. The best I could think of was a bug in your iostream library. I would try and get that sorted before you try out anything else though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the size of the file you have written as way of counting of the number questions you have so far.

```
ifstream file("filename");
file.seekg(0, ios_base::end);
streampos file_size = file.tellg();
file.close();
int next_question = file_size/sizeof(question) + 1;
```

But you have to be careful with deletes, suppose you have questions 1, 2, 3, 4 in your file and then you delete question 3. Now your file has 1, 2, 4 and so the method above will say the next question is 4, but you already have a question 4. One way to deal with this is to do *logical deletes*. Instead of actually deleting a question from a file you leave it there but mark it in some way so you know it's deleted. For instance you could set the question number to zero. So going back to the example above after you deleted question three you would have 1, 2, 0, 4. Now the file size method will correctly say the next question is 5.